# C# - Como gestiono el context menu de window?

Tags: c#

Necesito q las variables origen y el destino de la funcion CopyFile(origen, destino) se las pueda insertar, a traves de usar el click derecho de Mouse [Copiar/Pegar]. Espero hacerme entender, para esta solucion solo hay doc en c++, necesito saber si hay alguna para c#. En la imagen tengo seleccionada el Cortar, pero es Copiar. Gracias

```
void CopyFile(string origen, string destino) {

    FileStream fsout = new FileStream(destino, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    FileStream fsin = new FileStream(origen, FileMode.Open);
    byte[] bt = new byte[1048756];
    int readByte;
    while ((readByte = fsin.Read(bt,0, bt.Length)) >0)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        ms.Write(bt, 0, readByte);
        ms.Read(bt, 0, readByte);
        fsout.Write(bt, 0, readByte);                      
        //fsout.Write(bt, 0, readByte);
        worker.ReportProgress((int)(fsin.Position * 100 / fsin.Length));
        ms.Close();
    }

    fsin.Close();
    fsout.Close();
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Considera editar tu pregunta e insertar el código que tienes hasta el momento para intentar resolver tu problema. Te recomiendo revisar este enlace para que veas algunos tips para mejorar tus preguntas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Cúando se hacen preguntas genéricas sin un contexto, es más dificil encontrar respuestas.

Comment: Gracias por responder, espero q ahora entiendan la pregunta. Soy nuevo en este sitio.

Answer (score 1):

Gracias y disculpen las molestias. La solucion la encontre en este link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156975/copy-paste-event-listener-in-c-sharp

saludos

Comment: Que bueno que encontraste algo. No obstante, te recomiendo este artículo para que pienses 2 veces antes de incluir shell extensions en código administrado: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20061218-01/?p=28693

Comment: gracias, lo voy a revizar. saludos